# Proper way to run project (multiple SQLs) in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a homework project in PL/SQL, we have to create database (.sql files).
I have main directory with subdirectories "tables", "views", "procedures", "triggers", they contain .sql files that create associated objects for database. I know the correct order to run those files to create entire database from them. We have to send zip with them.
I want to create single .sql, or some script, or something alike that can run all those .sql files in correct order. Just login to DataGrip or anything like that, double click, and create tables, than views etc. (in order specified by me).
What is the proper way to do that? I'm quite sure there must be a way other than doing it by hand or copying everything into one huge .sql file (which I did and it works, but is ugly as hell).

Comment: I generally keep a single script file to create each object, then call a "master" script to reference each of them using the `@` symbol. I also group object types in their own directory, unless the install is fairly trivial. You can include the directory path after `@` before the file name (e.g. `@mydir/myfile.sql`).

Comment: Same here. Note, however, that the `@` mechanism is really a feature of `SQL*Plus`, and is not necessarily supported by other tools. Because of this, many Oracle database folks use the command-line SQL*Plus tool to do much of this kind of work.

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway to do your schema migrations.

Comment: @qalis In SQL Server Management Studio, just run backup on the database. This creates a single file. The studio also has an importer. On the DB, go-to tasks and generate scripts.